# Spring Integration FTP File Adapter on multiple instances processing duplicates

Tags: ftp, spring-integration, file-transfer, spring-integration-sftp

I'm new to Spring integration and I'm trying to do POC using Spring integration FTP file adapter to read files from FTP location.
When I deployed my application on two Tomcat instances, I see both instances are downloading files from FTP location.

I'm using virtual FTP server (Xlight) running on my machine. When I first copied files to remote directory, both instances downloaded files but when I copy few more files again to remote folder, either of the instances didn't pick newly added files. 
One of the things i also want to achieve when my application deployed on multiple instances, want to make sure one file is processed only once.

Please suggest what am i missing.

Below is my configuration file:

```
<bean id="ftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
  <property name="host" value="${ftp.host}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${ftp.port}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${ftp.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${ftp.password}"/>

    <!-- whether server should connect to client's port or client should connect server port for initiating file transfer -->
    <!--  <property name="clientMode" value="${ftp.clientMode}"/> -->
    <!-- different file types involve ASCII , EBCDIC , BINARY (default) -->
    <!--  <property name="fileType" value="${ftp.fileType}"/> --> 
    <!-- <property name="bufferSize" value="${ftp.bufferSize}"/> -->
</bean>

<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound" channel="ftpInboundChannel" session-factory="ftpSessionFactory" charset="UTF-8" auto-create-local-directory="true" delete-remote-files="false" remote-directory="/SpringFtpOutbound/remote" remote-file-separator="/" preserve-timestamp="false" temporary-file-suffix=".writing" local-filter="myFilter" local-directory="/work/SpringFtpInbound_2">
  <int:poller fixed-rate="2000" max-messages-per-poll="1"/>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="myFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
  <constructor-arg>
    <list>
      <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
        <constructor-arg name="store" ref="metadataStore"/>
        <constructor-arg value="*.*"/>
      </bean>
      <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.SimplePatternFileListFilter">
         <constructor-arg value="*.xml" />
      </bean>
    </list>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean> 

<bean id="redisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory" p:use-pool="true" p:host-name="localhost" p:port="6379" />
  <bean name="metadataStore" class="org.springframework.integration.redis.metadata.RedisMetadataStore">
    <constructor-arg name="connectionFactory" ref="redisConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<int-file:file-to-string-transformer id="myFileToStringTransfromer" input-channel="ftpInboundChannel" output-channel="transformChannel" />

<int-xml:xpath-splitter id="ftpFileSplitter" input-channel="transformChannel" output-channel="xpathSplitterChannel">
  <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="/bancsRequest/input"/>
</int-xml:xpath-splitter>

<int:transformer id="myCustomTransformer" ref="myTransformerBean" input-channel="xpathSplitterChannel" method="transform" output-channel="ftpOutboundChannel">
</int:transformer>

<bean id="myTransformerBean" class="com.ntrs.geh.ftp.file.poc.transformer.MyXmlPayloadTransformer"/>

<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="outboundChannelAdapter" channel="ftpOutboundChannel" jms-template="ftpOutQueueJmsTemplate" >
</int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same shared `metadataStore` approach, but for the `filter`.
And for this purpose Framework provides `FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-inbound